# How to parse xml with Classic asp?

Tags: xml, asp-classic

Hi I need to parse xml with Classic asp

here is the xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<int xmlns="http://url.com/WebServices">0</int>
```

I need to get 0

Could you please show me an example for this particular case? thank you

Answer (score 0):

ondrejsv is right - XMLDom is easy to learn. It's also a standard, so once you learn it in one language, it's the same in every other language.

Devguru.com has an excellent [reference](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/xmldom/quickref/node_nodeValue.html) with lots of examples... I've always found it a lot more useful than MSDN.

Comment: I don't understand the document.write portion of the code examples though FoxInSocks... I think that is JavaSCript isn't it?

Comment: Oh wow. I think the example on that page is supposed to say 'response.write', not 'document.write'.  

And they have gotten rid of the ability to contact them electronically. Maybe not such a hot reference after all. :-/

Answer (score -1):

You may do it easily with the MSXML COM library:

```
Dim xmlDoc
Set xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
```

and some [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

I don't give you a concrete example for your problem, start with learning [DOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757022%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) - it's easy.

Comment: This example in c#. I need in Classic Asp. I'm sorry but your answer not helpful

Comment: Michael, the examples are in JScript, not C# (I suppose you may use JScript in ASP3 pages, if I remember correctly). If you insist on more VBScript examples, there are [some even on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx).

Comment: Is it so difficult to browse the MSDN samples?