# how to load xml file in classic asp

Tags: xml, asp-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse xml with Classic asp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336046/how-to-parse-xml-with-classic-asp)

I want to load one XML file in classic ASP.

I am using

```
blnFileExists = objDom.Load(Server.MapPath("\a\abcfiles\admin\image_name.xml"))
```

but when I write `blnFileExists` it gives me false.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Write the contents of `objDOM.parseError.reason` to the response to find out why it didn't load.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the file path is as you have it written. The way you have it written, the file image_name.xml should be in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\a\abcfiles\admin. If that's not the case, then there's part of the problem.

You may want to instead give Server.MapPath a virtual path, like "/a/abcfiles/admin/image_name.xml". This path will be resolve to http://www.yourWebSite.com/a/abcfiles/admin/image_name.xml. Again, if this is not the correct path, adjust it as necessary.