# XML.Load always gives me False - Asp Classic

Tags: xml, asp-classic, vbscript

I want to load one XML file in classic ASP.

I am using

```
url = "http://www.url-exemplo.com/xml"

success = sXML.LoadXml(url)
```

My URL path gives me a XML file, but when I write success it gives me false.

What should I do?

This same code works fine in my VB6 code, my variable sucess gives me true. It only happen in my asp page.

Similar post: [how to load xml file in classic asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584095/how-to-load-xml-file-in-classic-asp)

But the answers don't help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
xml = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DomDocument")
xml.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", true
xml.async = false
xml.validateOnParse = false
xml.load("http://www.url-exemplo.com/xml")
```

Comment: Yes, John It was that I did. I set xml.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", true
and it solve my problem. I found it to in the two URLs which I post before.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sXML.Load(url)`.

`.LoadXml()` is for loading *actual* XML. [The documentation says so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you should read it.

I'm also pretty sure that your VB6 application uses the right function, you've just overlooked that detail.

Comment: I had the same problema using .load(url) =/

Comment: I found the solution, in this links: =D
         
http://forums.aspfree.com/asp-development-5/xmldom-object-error-parse-91519.html

http://forums.aspfree.com/code-bank-54/read-xml-url-91854.html

Comment: The other thread you've linked to in your question said it would be in `.parseError.reason`. Please include such error messages in your question next time.